# How do you turn off the multi touch capibility of the viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone

right now, the multi touch events causing the app to crash. I need to turn off the multi touch of capibility of the viewcontroller.

Comment: Multitouch is _not_ causing the app to crash: your incorrect handling of multitouch is causing the app to crash. My suggestion is that unless you have a reason (other than the crashing) to disable multitouch, that you just fix the underlying problem instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
viewController.view.multipleTouchEnabled=NO;
```